# PHP Code Error fopen not opening and writing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, web-services

When I run this PHP code it should store the comment but it doesn't write anything in comments.txt as it was supposed to do. Please find the error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

setcookie("username","admin", time()+3600);
setcookie("password","xss", time()+3600);

if($_POST['content']!=null){
$fp= fopen('comments.txt','a');
fwrite($fp,$_POST['content'], "</hr>");
fclose($fp);
}

echo nl2br(file_get_contents('comments.txt'));

?>

<h3>Post Your HTML Code here</h3>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="100"></textarea>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Post" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see a demo of this on my website [here](http://xss-by-ashesh.comuv.com/index.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($_POST['content']!=null){
```

The preferred (or preached) way to handle what you're after with this line is:

```
if(isset($_POST['content'])) {
```

---

For the actual error, it's because you're using the wrong arguments for `fwrite()`. From the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/fwrite), the arguments are:

```
int fwrite ( resource $handle , string $string [, int $length ] )
```

Drop the `"</hr>"` from the end and it'll fix it, like so:

```
fwrite($fp,$_POST['content']);
```

Comment: Updated with the solution, if the file permissions are set correctly already.

Answer (score 1):

have you checked your file has right permissions for apache to write it?

you can change permissions with **chmod**, an example:

```
// allow any operation for any user    
chmod("comments.txt", 0777);
```

Comment: Is comments.txt file owned by www-data  if not you need to change to www-data user so as php can write over it.

Comment: its rw-r--r--  permission